# CSS ID and order of properties

Tags: css

I have a quick question regarding CSS and ID.

This is what my CSS code looks like:

```
h1  {
   font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
   font-size: 36px;
   color: red;
}


#test h1 {
   color: green;
   font-size:10px;
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<h1 >asdfasdf<a href="/">test1</a></h1>
<h1 id="test">test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The output looks like this -> http://screencast.com/t/H2LOmJr7zd6f

My question is how come the H1 with ID test is not in green font?

If in the CSS I replace #test h1 with #test, it will work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the CSS ID selector wrong. Your current selector `#test h1` chooses `h1` elements which are **inside** an element with ID of `#test`

Using the ID is enough:

```
#test {
   color: green;
   font-size:10px;
}
```

P.S - If for some reason you really like to specify the element type with the ID (which is quite redundant for the ID is supposed to be unique), you can use this selector: `h1#test`

Answer (score 2):

I think `Italy` is right. If you want to indicate the element also you should do this:

```
h1#test { ... }
```